# Redshift SQL: How to get today's count and sum of counts from previous 3 days

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table with a date and some count like the following:

```
| Date       | Count |
| 2019-01-02 | 100   |
| 2019-01-03 | 101   |
| 2019-01-04 |  99   |
| 2019-01-05 |  95   |
| 2019-01-06 |  90   |
| 2019-01-07 |  88   |
```

Given this table, what I want to compute is to sum the counts for the previous 3 days for each date like the followings:

```
| Date       | Prev3DaysCount |
| 2019-01-02 |    0  |
| 2019-01-03 |  100  |
| 2019-01-04 |  201  |
| 2019-01-05 |  300  |
| 2019-01-06 |  295  |
| 2019-01-07 |  284  |
```

For example, the Prev3DaysCount of 284 for 2019-01-07 is from previous 3 days of (99+95+90). I figured that I can use SUM window function but I couldn't figure out how to limit the window to previous 3 days.

Comment: Do you always have a single row for one day? And are there missing day values (and if so, should the missing values count in the "previous 3 days")?

Comment: Yes only one row per day and there isn't any missing day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function (along with a `COALESCE` to transform the `null` (in the first row) to 0):

```
SELECT
  day,
  COALESCE(
    SUM(count) OVER (ORDER BY day ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
    0
  ) AS Prev3DaysCount
FROM t;
```

---

Returns:

```
┌────────────┬────────────────┐
│    day     │ prev3dayscount │
├────────────┼────────────────┤
│ 2019-01-02 │              0 │
│ 2019-01-03 │            100 │
│ 2019-01-04 │            201 │
│ 2019-01-05 │            300 │
│ 2019-01-06 │            295 │
│ 2019-01-07 │            284 │
└────────────┴────────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks @marth. What if there is any missing day(s) in the last 3 days? I don't have the situation yet but it might in the future!

Comment: @kee: you would need to `LEFT JOIN` on a "date" table containing a list of all dates (covering the dateranges your application use) to fill in the gaps. On Postgresql you would usually use `generate_series()` but I don't think it's available on Redshift.